# Defining the rotation angle between the template and the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

In general, my goal is for the UV printer to print images on badges. There is some input image with badges, I need to determine the position of the objects, rotation relative to the template, and then apply the printed image to the resulting location and rotate it to the desired angle. The first stage, identifying the location of the icons, was successful. To do this, I used an `HSV` colour scheme and a saturation layer, then a Canny edge detector, called a function to find outlines, and got a bounding box for the icons. Here is the Python code using the OpenCV library:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import improclib
import cv2 as cv

import random as rng

from z_final_lib import getOrientation


# load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
image = cv.imread('b2.jpg')
gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

toCanny = image
toCanny = improclib.select_colorsp(toCanny, colorsp='sat')

cv.imshow("Original", image)

canny_output = cv.Canny(toCanny, 30, 250)

canny_output = improclib.morph_op(canny_output, 'close', 3)

cv.imshow("canny_output", canny_output)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(canny_output, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print('contours len = ', len(contours))

sorted_cnt = sorted(contours, key=cv.contourArea, reverse=True)

bx, by, w, h = cv.boundingRect(sorted_cnt[0])
max_area = w * h
print('max_area')
print(max_area)

external_contours = []
min_area_ratio = 0.05
# Область изображения.
im_area = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]
for cnt in sorted_cnt:
    bx, by, w, h = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
    cnt_area = w * h
    print(cnt_area)
    # Удалите очень мелкие дефекты.
    if (1 - cnt_area / max_area) < 0.6:
        external_contours.append(cnt)

contours = external_contours
print('contours len = ', len(contours))

filled_image = np.zeros_like(canny_output)
for c in contours:
    cv.drawContours(filled_image, [c], 0, (255, 255, 255), -1)

filled_image = improclib.morph_op(filled_image, 'open', 3)


cv.imshow('+++', filled_image)

rng.seed(12345)

contours_poly = [None] * len(contours)
boundRect = [None] * len(contours)
centers = [None] * len(contours)
radius = [None] * len(contours)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    contours_poly[i] = cv.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
    boundRect[i] = cv.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
    centers[i], radius[i] = cv.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i])

drawing = image.copy()
for i in range(len(contours)):
    color = (rng.randint(0, 256), rng.randint(0, 256), rng.randint(0, 256))
    cv.drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color)
    cv.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])),
                 (int(boundRect[i][0] + boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1] + boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)

cv.imshow('Contours', drawing)

cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Got quite a good result:

[image]
But next I need to determine the angle of rotation of the icons relative to the template. But this is a dead end. The badges are not exactly the same and have some defects. I tried Feature Detection methods, but they do not give the desired result. The icons are considered different.
Here is the code

```
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
kp = sift.detect(gray, None)
img = cv.drawKeypoints(gray, kp, img)
cv.imshow('sift_keypoints.jpg', img)
```

And result:

[image]

Cropped coins

[image: description]
[image: description]

[image: description]
[image: description]

Comment: Post separate images of some of your cropped coins. Looks like there are scale differences that you need to account before rotation analysis, since the sizes do not look the same. Then you will need to find the centers of each coin.  One thought would be to convert to (log?) polar coordinates and then do 1D template matching to get the rotation.  See for example phase correlation in log-polar domain to do the matching, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/506761

Answer (score 0):

From the attached result image, your SIFT keypoints are all of same size with very small radius. Your icons(coins) have coarser features , so SIFT features spanning smaller radii will not capture the detail correctly. So try increasing the descriptor radius/size.
Also you should do this for all icons independently and then run a RANSAC between them to find the rotation.